# Python Crawling - Requests faster

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to make a **Web Crawling do requests and bring the responses complete and quickly**, if possible.

I come from the Java language. I used two "frameworks" and neither fully satisfied my intent.

The *Jsoup* had the *request/response* fast but wore incomplete data when the page had a lot of information. The *Apache HttpClient* was exactly the opposite of this, reliable data but very slow.

I've looked over some of Python modules and I'm testing **Scrapy**. In my searches, I was unable to conclude whether it is the **fastest** and brings the **data consistently**, or is there some other better, even more verbose or difficult.

Second, Python is a **good language** for this purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 votes for Scrapy. For the past several weeks I have been writing crawlers of massive car forums, and Scrapy is absolutely incredible, fast, and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

looking for something to "do requests and bring the responses complete and quickly" makes no sense.

A. Any HTTP library will give you the complete headers/body the server responds with.

B. how "quick" a web request happens is generally dictated by your network connection and server's response time, not the client you are using.

so with those requirements, anything will do.

check out the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package.  It is an excellent http client library for Python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be practical: the fact is that a library is significantly faster than the other. It may in its internal implementation prioritize data consistency, instead of providing quick return.

What I need to know, if there is one that has a good balance of it.

I am interested in your link could post it again, please?

Comment: Even if this were not, I liked this link. I'm reading now, thanks @furas